How to make a Data Modifying CTE abort if an update only partially succeeded?
I am wondering if it is possible to add some kind of check to make a data modifying CTE abort if an update is partially successful. Attached is a minimal query that represents the problem. I would like the query to fail if updated_rows has not updated the 3 rows specified in the WHERE IN clause.
This is easy to achieve if this query is rewritten as an interactive transaction, but I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve this while keeping things as a single data modifying CTE.
with updated_rows as (
    update some_table
    set status = 'SUCCEEDED'
    where id in ('a', 'b', 'c') and status = 'PENDING'
    returning *
), more_updated_rows as (
    update another_table
    set total = total + 3
    where completed = false 
    returning *
) select * from more_updated_rows


A query only fails if it encounters an error. You could provoke one in the outer query:
WITH ...
SELECT 1 / (count(*) = 3)::integer
FROM more_updated_rows

But that's awkward, and the error will be meaningless. The better solution is to get the result count on the client side, and if it is not as desired, roll back the transaction and report an error.

Thanks for the answer. I'm a little surprised there's not a more elegant way of achieving this, as it seems like a useful component for building CTEs that deal with many rows and limited optimistic concurrency.

WITH 
matched_rows_amount (amount, distinct_amount) AS (
    SELECT COUNT(id), COUNT(DISTINCT id)
    FROM some_table
    WHERE id IN ('a', 'b', 'c') 
      AND status = 'PENDING'
),
updated_rows (id) AS (
    UPDATE some_table
    SET status = 'SUCCEEDED'
    WHERE id IN ('a', 'b', 'c') AND status = 'PENDING'
    AND (SELECT amount, distinct_amount 
         FROM matched_rows_amount) = (3,3)
    RETURNING id
)
SELECT matched_rows_amount.amount, 
       matched_rows_amount.distinct_amount, 
       COUNT(updated_rows.id) updated_amount
FROM updated_rows
CROSS JOIN matched_rows_amount;

1st CTE - selects and counts the amount of rows which will be updated. Additionally checks that these are distinct rows (i.e. all 3 rows to be updated contains different column values, not 3 dups of one value) - this can be removed when the marker column is unique and not nullable.
2nd CTE - updates rows with additional condition which checks the amount of rows to be updated. If the amount of rows to be updated is not 3 then none row will be updated.
Outer query returns the amounts for the whole operation status additional check. It must return (3,3,3) or (0,0,0).
PS. The query does not generate any error - the situation when not all values from the values list are present in the table is not error but normal process flow. If this is logical error then according exception must be generated by the client (I have tried, the amount does not match, I panic).

Thanks for the answer. I think if you want, you can edit out the assumption the key is not distinct as it makes your answer a bit less clear on first read. I think the outer count is not necessary (?), as the 2nd CTE will be building on the same snapshot seen by the 1st. The outer query can also return (1, 0, 0) or (2, 0, 0) as well. The extra WHERE check in the 2nd CTE seems to be the only part that is necessary.
The general approach you took is good, although the extra WHERE condition will have to be propagated into other update clauses to make them also do nothing, which could get messy.

@cynodon: "the 2nd CTE will be building on the same snapshot seen by the 1st": not necessarily, not under READ COMMITTED (the default)

not sure why you rejected my edit, but the way it stands now, your SQL won't parse.

@Quassnoi not sure why you rejected my edit It does not match my opinion. You may create your answer with your own version of the query based on my one. your SQL won't parse Yes, there are 2 incorrect constructions. 1) Postgres does not support implicit row constructor, so subquery in updated_rows must be moved to FROM clause; 2) Outer query needs in additional GROUP BY 1,2, or counting subquery must be placed to the output list instead of SUM and CROSS JOIN.
